# Após migração Wordpress faz download e não exibe página

Tags: wordpress

O problema é o seguinte, após a migração do wordpress de uma hospedagem para a outra ocorre um problema, ele não exibe nada apenas faz o download de um arquivo chamado "download", tive este mesmo erro uma vez mas foi resolvido pela própria hospedagem.

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: O .htaccess é somente isso mesmo? Tua nova hospedagem é Apache ou é IIS?

Comment: Apache meu camarada

Comment: Se puder dar mais detalhes facilitaria

Comment: Não tem muito detalhe, é praticamente isso, migrei o site por backup do CPanel e depois já começou a dar esse erro, ele simplesmente baixa um arquivo chamado "download".

Comment: Qual o contuedo desse arquivo, tentou abrir no notepad.exe?

Answer (score 2):

Sua pergunta deu muita pouca informação, não tem como deduzir muita coisa, mas talvez isso seja o problema, se o .htaccess estiver na mesma pasta que o wordpress (**somente se estiver**) retira o rewritebase e o / da frente do index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```